# Android studio Throw nio exception?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have just update android studio 3.2 an i am getting the Exception java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException:

```
 Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1

 Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
```

Comment: show your code .

Comment: @Rahul Chaube, gradle version?

Comment: Question is not clear